# Error with global variable

Tags: python, python-3.x, pygame

Whenever I start my game and it loads my menu I get the error "SyntaxWarning: name 'finishes' is assigned to before global declaration". How do I fix this? I doesn't disrupt my game but any error should be fixed. I have cut down the below code to just show the essential code.

```
def load_level(level):
    walls = []
    players = []
    finishes = []
    x = y = 0
    for row in levels[level]:
        for col in row:
            if col == "W":
                walls.append(Wall((x, y)))
            if col == "P":
                players.append(Player((x, y)))
            if col == "F":
                finishes.append(Finish1((x, y)))
            if col == "G":
                finishes.append(Finish2((x, y)))
            if col == "H":
                finishes.append(Finish3((x, y)))
            if col == "I":
                finishes.append(Finish4((x, y)))
            x += 40.96
        y += 30.72
        x = 0
    return walls, players, finishes

walls, players, finishes = load_level(currentLevel)

def Menu():
    runnin = True
    while runnin:
        clock.tick(60)
        screen.fill(BLACK)
        mouseclick = pygame.mouse.get_pressed()
        for e in pygame.event.get():
            if e.type == pygame.QUIT:
                pygame.quit()
                sys.exit(0)
            if e.type == pygame.KEYDOWN:
                if e.key == pygame.K_ESCAPE:
                    pygame.quit()
                    sys.exit(0)
        for option in options:
            if option.rect.collidepoint(pygame.mouse.get_pos()):
                option.hovered = True
                if mouseclick[0] == 1:
                    if option.text == "Easy":
                        global currentlevel, walls, players, finishes
                        walls, players, finishes = load_level(0)
                        currentlevel = 0
                        main()
                    elif option.text == "Medium":
                        global currentlevel, walls, players, finishes
                        walls, players, finishes = load_level(1)
                        currentlevel = 1
                        main()
                    elif option.text == "Hard":
                        global currentlevel, walls, players, finishes
                        walls, players, finishes = load_level(2)
                        currentlevel = 2
                        main()
                    elif option.text == "Help":
                        Help()
                    else:
                        runnin = False
            else:
                option.hovered = False
            option.draw()
            screen.blit(title_font.render("Amazeing Race", True, GREY), (130, 50))
        pygame.display.update()
    pygame.quit()
    sys.exit(0)
```

Comment: Could you provide the full error traceback? That would be able to point out which line has the error.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The problem here is that you are declaring `global` on variables more than once. Globals should be declared at the start of the function. Read more [here](http://effbot.org/zone/syntaxwarning-name-assigned-to-before-global-declaration.htm). To solve this, simply move `global currentlevel, walls, players, finishes` to the top of your function like so:

```
def Menu():
    global currentlevel, walls, players, finishes
    runnin = True
    # more code...
```

## Concepts

Here are some tests that I hope will help you understand what will and what will not raise the `SyntaxWarning`.

1.Do not declare a variable before a global statement.

```
a = 3
global a
```

This **will** raise the `SyntaxWarning`.

2.You may declare a variable global in functions even after you declared it outside of the function.

```
a = 3
def asdf():
    global a
    a = 2
```

This **will not** raise the `SyntaxWarning`.

3.In a function, you may declare any other variable before the global declaration (However, not advised).

```
a = 3
def asdf():
    b = 2
    global a
    a = 2
```

This **will not** raise `SyntaxWarning`.

4.In a function, you may only declare globals before assignment even when enclosed in if else statements.

```
a = 0

def asdf():
    if a == 3:
        global a
        a = 2
        return a
    else:
        global a
        return a
```

This **will** raise the `SyntaxWarning`. As you can see, this is more similar to what you are doing.

### In summary:

Declare all globals before declaration in the given scope even if the `global` code may not be reached.